# Is there a way to exchange data between framebuffers in webgl2? (attempting multistage image processing)

Tags: javascript, glsl, framebuffer, webgl2

I'm attempting to translate my raw javascript code for image processing into GLSL in webgl2 to achieve performance gains.
simply explained, this is my approach:

per frame:
1)set camera stream video as texture
2)apply some effects in first frame buffer
3)set result as texture to second frame buffer
3)apply some effects in second frame buffer
4)set result as texture to third frame buffer
5)apply some effects in third frame buffer
...
last step) set null frame buffer and draw to canvas with final effects.

note: effects are progressive and based on finished result of previous effect

my question is, i want my fragment shader to write to an array of data/metadata other than the standard fragmentOutput, to be used in next frame buffer for certain operations.

so technically, i want my first shader-pass to save and array, and second shader-pass to use these saved values. i'm looking for what kind of structure/data/object to use for this and if possible, how to use it

code goes something like this:

```
//-- Load video frame and snapshot
refresh_texture();

//-- use first buffer to draw
GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffers[0]);
GL.uniform1f(_stageNumber, 0);
GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// for the next draw, use the texture we just rendered to.
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
GL.uniform1f(_stageNumber, 1);
//-- use second buffer to draw
GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffers[1]);
GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Comment: TMM, the most elegant solution is to allocate 2 texture-backed [framebuffer objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object); let\`s call them F₀ and F₁. After that all that`s left is to write some shaders that fetch data from the texture belonging to Fₙ and process it, drawing the result to F₁₋ₙ (which eventually results in drawing to its texture).

Comment: This is C++, but it should point you in the right direction to read from the [previews rendered frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749733/opengl-implementing-multipass)